# How to pass a dictionary to Django-template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am not able to get the value of dictionary at Django-template. Take a look on `views.py`

```
 def subnet_network(request, page=None):
     ipv4_sub_net , ipv6_sub_net= get_netmask(user=request.user)
     extra_context = {
         'ipv4_net': ipv4_sub_net,
         'ipv6_net': ipv6_sub_net
         }
     return direct_to_template(request, 'networks/subnet_network.html',
                          extra_context=extra_context)
```

To get the value of these two dictionary and the `subnet_network.html`. I wrote the following code:

```
 <tbody>
  {% for k,v in ipv4_net.items %}
     <tr>
         <td>
             {{ v }}
         </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

and the same above code is for ipv6_net dictionary 
While i check my values in dictionary using `pdb.set_trace()`. It print like this:

```
 (Pdb) print ipv4_sub_net
 [{'ipv4_sub_net': u'255.0.0.0'}, {'ipv4_sub_net': u'255.255.255.255'}]

 (Pdb) print ipv6_sub_net
 [{'ipv6_sub_net': u'/12'}, {'ipv6_sub_net': u'/128'}]
```

is there are something wrong with the code?

Comment: In your template, what's the `d` in `d.items`? From the view, you seem to be passing in `ipv4_net` and `ipv6_net` as individual vars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the print statement you have a list with 2 dictionaries, not one dictionary with 2 elements. Thus ipv4_sub_net.items is not valid.

If you do this you will see it:

```
for v in ipv4_sub_net:
    print v
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. Yes i got to know that it is a list but how i print with in template i did by putting ** {% for k in ipv4_net %} {{k}} ** but it print like this     **{'ipv4_sub_net':u'255.0.0.0'} {'ipv4_sub_net':u'255.0.0.0'} **  . I mean now how to print this dictionary in template